# Is it permissible for men to watch sports of women via Television? (Shi'a View)

Tags: sharia, shiism, men, non-mahram, tv

I was wondering if it is permissible(Halal) for boys to watch the sport matches which their players are young girls.

*Note: I’m looking for the viewpoint of Shi'a about it.*

Comment: The general rule for all of the questions of this kind is that it is not permissible if it can lead to inclination toward immorality and losing virtues.

Answer (score 1):

Salam on alaykom.

If it's not any pleasure, if it's not any fear to be placed in sin , if girl is not Muslim or if she's Muslim you don’t know her , no problem.

**Source:**

- [http://farsi.khamenei.ir](http://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-content?id=102#1183)